# Unable to add a Delegated Permission to an Azure AD application registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am new to Azure but have been messing around trying to get a feel for it.  I have successfully used Azure AD to secure an API using application permissions. The typical example of creating an app role in the API registration that has an allowed member type of Application and then selecting and granting via API Permissions > Add Permission > Application Permissions of the client app registration.

Next I would like to implement OpenID Connect Authentication & Authorization where I grant a role to a user instead of the client web app. However the Delegated Permissions "tab" is not enabled. I have made sure that there is an app role created in the API as follows. I have also tried it with the app role with a allowedMemberTypes set to Users only but with the same disabled Delegated Permissions result.

Delegated Permissions Disabled:

[image]

```
"appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User",
            "Application"
        ],
        "description": "Users and Applications with this role can consume the Pricing Model API",
        "displayName": "Pricing Model Cosumer",
        "id": "62d4b7d0-2e37-4a28-8918-098e3eabdc58",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "PricingModel.Consumer"
    }
],
```

I have searched for hours and only found results pertaining to the Application Permissions option being disabled and the answer to this is always to verify that there is an application role to select in the specified API registration.

Is there something elsewhere that I may be missing? Is there a more appropriate way or place to ask this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegated permissions are not defined in appRoles. You can add them instead in the "Expose an API" section of the app registration or in the oauth2Permissions.

To [add the scope in the app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration):

**Exposing delegated permissions (scopes)**

1. Select Expose an API in the application registration.**
2. Select Add a scope.
3. If prompted, accept the proposed application ID URI (api://{clientId}) by selecting Save and Continue.
4. Specify these values:

- Select Scope name and enter access_as_user.
- Select Who can consent and make sure Admins and users is selected.
- Select Admin consent display name and enter Access xxxservice as a user.
- Select Admin consent description and enter Accesses the xxx web API as a user.
- Select User consent display name and enter Access xxx as a user.
- Select User consent description and enter Accesses the xxx web API as a user.
- Keep the State value set to Enabled.

5. Select Add scope.

To define the delegated permissions in oauth2Permissions, see:
https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: Thank you . That  I will try this tomorrow. Is there a use case where you might use an app role with an AllowedMemberTypes of "User" ?